# Isn't this a correct but very efficient and simple way of solving the 0-1 knapsack?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, knapsack-problem

As I understand it, in a 0-1 knapsack problem, only 0 or 1 objects of the same variant are allowed. Wouldn't it be better to just divide every weight by it's value to get the respectiv ratios and then just take every ratio beginning from the largest and put it in the knapsack until the maximum allowed weight is reached? Wouldn't its time complexity be better than the dynamic programming solution and obviously better than bruteforcing?

Comment: It's simple and efficient, but doesn't always produce the optimal solution. If you can't find a counterexample yourself, search for "greedy 0-1 knapsack" and Google yields a ton of links.

Comment: That greedy trick is well known, but only works for the linear relaxation of knapsack. Otherwise you can (misleadingly) write "until the maximum weight is reached", but it may never be reached, early choices can force you into a corner where you have leftover space that no items fits into though you might have filled it if an early item hadn't been chosen. If you choose value=weight then it's obvious how that can lead to suboptimal solutions - it's a problem in general but that just makes it obvious.

Comment: Weights: 4,3,2. Max total: 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the 0-1 Knapsack problem is to find if the maximum value occurs if an item is put into the knapsack or not included in the knapsack.  This prevents the problem where including an item results in an unfillable space in the knapsack.  A greedy approach that always includes an object could result in an unfillable space in the knapsack.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although I had heard that there is some greedy algorithm, but I never bothered to look it up.